# Error when implementing Newton Raphson method to vba

Tags: vba, excel, math, nonlinear-functions, newtons-method

This is a long one I know but I would really appreciate the help.
I am trying to code the [Newton Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) into VBA, Code shown below:

### Code:

```
'Code illustrating Newton-Raphson scheme for the equation:
' f(x) = arcCos((x-BCos(H))/S)-arcSin((Bsin(H)-y)/S)

Const ep = 1E-23: Const imax = 100
Private x As Long: Private xnew As Single: Private xl As Single
Private xu As Single: Private xm As Single: Private xmold As Single: Private A As Single: Private B As Single
Private C As Single: Private D As Single
Private i As Integer
Private Failed As Boolean: Private Converged As Boolean

Sub Setup()
Failed = False
Converged = False
i = 0
End Sub

Sub NRRoot()
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
For rw = 2 To 3601

x = sht.Cells(rw, 48)

Setup
Do
Dim fx As Single: Dim fprimex As Single
fx = Application.Acos((Range("O9") - Range("AI5") * Cos(x)) / Range("AL5")) - Application.Asin((Range("AI5") * Sin(x) - Range("P9")) / Range("AL5"))
fprimex = -(Range("AI5") * Sin(x) * Range("AL5")) / (Range("AL5") * Sqr((Range("AL5") ^ 2) - (Range("O9") ^ 2) + 2 * Range("O9") * Range("AI5") * Cos(x) - (Range("AI5") ^ 2) * (Cos(x) ^ 2))) - (Range("AI5") * Cos(x) * Range("AL5")) / (Range("AL5") * Sqr((Range("AL5") ^ 2) - (Range("AI5") ^ 2) * (Sin(x) ^ 2) + 2 * Range("P9") * Range("AI5") * Sin(x) - (Range("P9") ^ 2)))
xnew = x - fx / fprimex
Dim er As Single
er = Abs(2 * (xnew - x) / (xnew + x))
If er < ep Then
Converged = True
ElseIf i >= imax Then
Failed = True
Else
i = i + 1
x = xnew
End If
Loop Until Converged Or Failed
If Failed Then
sht.Cells(rw, 50).Value = "Iteration failed"
Else
sht.Cells(rw, 50).Value = xnew
End If
sht.Cells(rw, 51).Value = i
Next

End Sub
```

### Problem:

I am getting the error message: "Run-time error'13': Type Mismatch", and using the debugger it is shown on this line of code:

```
fx = Application.Acos((Range("O9") - Range("AI5") * Cos(x)) / Range("AL5")) - Application.Asin((Range("AI5") * Sin(x) - Range("P9")) / Range("AL5"))
```

*I think* it has something to do with the `Application.Acos` & `Application.Asin`, however I am not too sure. I was having troubles with it for a while and I did some searching and found [This](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/60646-acos-function-not-defined.html) showing that I have to put `Application.Acos` or `Application.WorksheetFunction`. The values being put in are all in radians from -pi to pi.

If it isn't because of the above text, then *I think* it could have something to do with the parameters that I am defining... right at the top there it says `Private x As Long` where maybe it has to be something else. I have tried troubleshooting, but it never really worked :(

The values in cells O9, P9, AI5, and AL5 are listed respectively: 2000, 3000, 5700, 2924.99

P.S. 
The reason why I am needing to use this method is because I am trying to calculate the angles of 2 sticks when given a certain point x,y (O9,P9). I need these angles to be able to calculate the center of mass of the two sticks. Once I have the center of mass I can then finish my calculations for the project I am doing. I know there are other (much better) methods to do this problem, like wolfram mathematica, however there are other parts to the project that need to be on excel. Therefore to run everything as smooth as possible, sadly, I need to do all of this on excel.

P.P.S.
This is not my code by the way, I copied it from [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?798121-RESOLVED-VBA-code-to-apply-Newton-Raphson-method-to-ith-number-of-rows), however I think it does actually solve the Newton Raphson Method.

### Solution

I had the numbers for arcSin starting at pi and going to -pi  instead of 90 going to -90...

If I can figure out a better way to program the Newton Raphson Method, I will be sure to make a new post about it.

Comment: You might have text in one of the cells. Btw, why is `x` of type `Long` and not a floating point number?

Comment: @NicoSchertler it was originally of type `single` but I was troubleshooting and I guess never changed it back. I will try making x of another type. What is the equivalent to `float`? Do you know?

Comment: I double-checked, there is no text in one of the cells. @NicoSchertler

Comment: Then try to store the values in some variables first and you will see if there is a conversion error. E.g. `Dim B As Single : B = Range(...)`. This will make your code cleaner, anyway.

Comment: so I changed `x = sht.Cells(rw, 48)` to ` Dim x As Single: x = sht.Cells(rw, 48)`... is that what you meant? because it is still giving me the same error, same location. In Column AU I have a range of radians values from pi to -pi

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant (for all the variables in your code). If the error is still in the formula for `fx`, then it is probably not a parsing error. You can try to split the formula into separate parts and check what the problematic one is.

Comment: So, I split it up, doing this: `fx1 = Application.Acos((Range("O9") - Range("AI5") * Cos(x)) / Range("AL5"))`
 `fx2 = -Application.Asin((Range("AI5") * Sin(x) - Range("P9")) / Range("AL5"))`  `fx = fx1 + fx2` and the problem is in fx2

Comment: Why aren't you using the variables instead of all these `Range`  calls? That was the whole purpose of the first check.

Comment: Because the variables may change in different instances. I will however for this purpose change the `range` to the variables

Comment: It still gives me the same error message on fx2 when I change the range cells to their variables

Comment: Make sure those values are in radians, not degrees.  Trig functions in every language accept radians as their argument.  Check ranges for inverse functions as well.  Odd looking NR implementation.

Comment: All the values are in radians @duffymo. I thought I mentioned that in the question, but I guess not. I will add it right now. Judging by your comment there, it seems as though you've seen a better way to code the NR method, could you show me that way?

Comment: Breaking news: when I hover over fx1, a text box shows: fx1= Error 2036. Does this mean anything to you? @NicoSchertler

Comment: That suggests an error value in one of your cells.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it done properly for 1D and mutlidimensional problems in Numerical Recipes.  I'm guessing that your problem is for root finding of 1D functions, not for linear algebra solution of nonlinear problems.

Comment: It is of a 2D function... do i have something majorly wrong here?

Comment: I didn't read your link.  I don't know.  Take a look at Numerical Recipes.  You will have to translate C to VB.

Comment: @duffymo it seems to me that I have to subscribe to this Numerical Recipes information source in order to access that information. Could you post the code that you have seen work as an answer?

Comment: Nope.  I'm not going to break their licensing agreement.  I bought the book.  Maybe you could, too.  If you really want to persist with the code you have, why would you not step through in a debugger and figure out where you went wrong?  You could have fixed it by now.

Comment: Okay. I would if I could, however, I am at work and my boss isn't going to approve of a debugger for one problem that I have. Furthermore not everyone has the funds to be spending $50+ on a book that they may only need once.

Comment: it has been solved

Answer (score 1):

I split your codes into multiple subroutines and removed some unused variables. Run the Sub Main() will give the final results.

VBA itself has the sin and cos functions. You can use them as `VBA.sin()` and `VBA.cos()`, or simply `sin()` and `cos()`. The Acos and Asin are included in `Application.WorksheetFunction`, so you can use them as `Application.WorksheetFunction.Acos` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Asin`.

In your original code of fprimex, there is an occurrence of `Range("Cos(x)")`, which is not the valid syntax for the `Worksheet.Range` property, unless you have a Range that has the name of "Cos(x)". Also, please check whether my version of fprimex matches yours since I haven't done calculus for some time.

You should be careful with cases when `fPrimeX = 0`, or `abs(x) >= 1` when `sqr(1-x^2)` is on the denominator. Crude exit options for the above cases are include in the attached codes.

```
Option Explicit

Const ep As Double = 1E-23: Const iMax As Long = 100

Private FuncCoeffB As Double
Private FuncCoeffS As Double
Private FuncCoeffX As Double
Private FuncCoeffY As Double

Private sht As Worksheet
Private wksFunc As WorksheetFunction

Private Sub SetExcelVariables()
    Set sht = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    ' Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wksFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
End Sub

Private Sub SetFunctionCoefficients()
    With sht
        FuncCoeffX = .Range("O9")
        FuncCoeffY = .Range("P9")

        FuncCoeffB = .Range("AI5")
        FuncCoeffS = .Range("AL5")
    End With
End Sub

Private Function fx(ArgX As Double) As Double
    Dim fx1 As Double
    Dim fx2 As Double

    If VBA.Abs((FuncCoeffX - FuncCoeffB * VBA.Cos(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) > 1 Or _
        VBA.Abs((-FuncCoeffY + FuncCoeffB * VBA.Sin(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) > 1 Then

        Exit Function
    End If

    fx1 = wksFunc.Acos((FuncCoeffX - FuncCoeffB * VBA.Cos(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS)
    fx2 = -wksFunc.Asin((-FuncCoeffY + FuncCoeffB * VBA.Sin(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS)

    fx = fx1 + fx2
End Function

Private Function fPrimeX(ArgX As Double) As Double
    Dim fPrimeX1 As Double
    Dim fPrimeX2 As Double

    If (((FuncCoeffX - FuncCoeffB * VBA.Cos(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) ^ 2) >= 1 Or _
        (((-FuncCoeffY + FuncCoeffB * VBA.Sin(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) ^ 2) >= 1 Then

        Exit Function
    End If

    fPrimeX1 = _
        -FuncCoeffB / FuncCoeffS * VBA.Sin(ArgX) / _
        VBA.Sqr( _
            1 - ((FuncCoeffX - FuncCoeffB * VBA.Cos(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) ^ 2)

    fPrimeX2 = _
        -FuncCoeffB / FuncCoeffS * VBA.Cos(ArgX) / _
        VBA.Sqr( _
            1 - ((-FuncCoeffY + FuncCoeffB * VBA.Sin(ArgX)) / FuncCoeffS) ^ 2)

    fPrimeX = fPrimeX1 + fPrimeX2
End Function

Private Function NewtonRaphson(ByVal ArgX As Double) As Variant
    Dim ResFx As Double
    Dim ResFPrimeX As Double

    Dim xNew As Double
    Dim er As Double

    Dim iIter As Long
    Dim Converged As Boolean
    Dim Failed As Boolean

    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    ReDim ReturnValue(1 To 1, 1 To 2) ' An array with a size of 1-by-2.

    Do
        ResFx = fx(ArgX)
        ResFPrimeX = fPrimeX(ArgX)

        If ResFPrimeX = 0 Then
            Failed = True
        Else
            xNew = ArgX - ResFx / ResFPrimeX
        End If

        If xNew + ArgX = 0 Then
            Failed = True
        Else
            er = VBA.Abs(2 * (xNew - ArgX) / (xNew + ArgX))
        End If

        If er < ep Then
            Converged = True
        ElseIf iIter >= iMax Then
            Failed = True
        Else
            iIter = iIter + 1
            ArgX = xNew
        End If
    Loop Until Converged Or Failed

    If Failed Then
        ReturnValue(1, 1) = "Iteration failed"
    Else
        ReturnValue(1, 1) = xNew
    End If

    ReturnValue(1, 2) = iIter

    NewtonRaphson = ReturnValue
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rngTarget As Excel.Range
    Dim rngResult As Excel.Range
    Dim xValue As Double

    Call SetExcelVariables
    Call SetFunctionCoefficients

    For rw = 2 To 12
        Set rngTarget = sht.Cells(rw, 48)
        xValue = rngTarget.Value

        Set rngResult = rngTarget.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 2)
        rngResult.Value = NewtonRaphson(xValue)
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to execute it, Run-Time error '424': Object Required pops up when going through `SetFunctionCoefficientss()` `FuncCoeffX = .Range("O9")` however there is a value in O9.

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer with `sht = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` in `SetExcelVariables`. Could you check whether this would solve the error?

Comment: The same error pops up... are you wanting me to insert the new code into a new module?

Comment: Yes please paste all the codes into a new module. If it still fails, try pasting the codes into a new Workbook to avoid any variable naming conflicts.

Comment: So when I place the macros into a new module in a new work book, no errors appear, however, I am populating O9 P9 AI5 AL5... what other cells need to be populated in order for this to work??

Comment: You may choose which cells to fill by modifying the cell address in the `SetFunctionCoefficients` procedure. In the `Main()` procedure, you can also modify the cell address of `rngTarget` and `rngResult`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173160/discussion-between-pauldragoonm-and-jakek).